# Can a metal barrier mounted on a system of springs with a right elastic constant save a weak object from a bullet?

Tags: energy, collision, elasticity

My question is motivated by the fact that a lot of objects or vehicles that are important can be hit by bullets.Will a barrier mounted on a system of springs efficiently attenuate the kinetic energy of a bullet?

Comment: You can already buy commercial armor that stops bullets. Perhaps it would help if you could be more specific about how you hope your system could improve on existing armor. (e.g., you want it to be lighter weight? You want it to be more compact? you want it to cost less? etc?)

Comment: A metal barrier, even without springs, can save a "weak object" from a bullet if the barrier is thick enough. (Note: just how thick is "enough" is going to depend on the material properties of the metal that you choose, and on the kinetic energy, momentum, and material properties of the bullet that you wish to defend against.)

Comment: Many things can indeed be hit by bullets. Few actually are, depending of course on where you are in the world.

Comment: I think your idea is essentially how bulletproof armor works, except the material is elastic (and not usually metal).